# How do I search a database for a table with a certain word

Tags: mysql, oracle, select

I have a database with hundreds of tables and I want to search all the tables to find a table which contains the word Job.

So something like

```
Select all tables where name = 'JOB';
```

Comment: Is your database under Oracle or mySQL? the solution/answer would not be the same as they don't have the same "metadata" objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dba access, you can do this

SELECT *
  FROM all_tables
  WHERE upper(table_name) like '℅JOB℅'

Answer (score 0):

The result of following query is all tables that 'JOB' is partial of name of those

```
 SELECT o.object_Name, OBJECT_TYPE
      FROM user_objects o
     WHERE o.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
       AND o.OBJECT_NAME like '%JOB%'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

For MYSQL, you can use information_schema.TABLES 
Like,
select * from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'YOUR_DB_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%SEARCHWORD%'